# Django and Gunicorn: 403 Forbidden

Tags: python, webserver, gunicorn

I have a django application inside /home//my_app that I am trying to deploy using gunicorn:

```
sudo gunicorn --workers=2 -b :8081 tutorial.wsgi:application
```

After deploying the application with the command above, I log into another ssh instance (on the same server) and run the following command:

```
wget 127.0.0.1:8081
```

This returns a 403 FORBIDDEN.

Things I have tried: 
1. Tried to chmod 755, and even 777, in app directory (Did not work) 
2. Tried to move app directory to /etc/www/myapp (Did not work) 
3. Tried to run all commands using root access (Did not work)

It is worth noting that I am not that familiar with linux and that this error is literally driving me crazy.

**SOLVED IT:** 
    after downloading cURL, in order to see the http header, it turned out that the service worked, but returned a 403 because a missing token authorization. Oops.

Comment: Do you have a handler defined in your WSGI app that responds to a GET request on `/`?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have coded views.py and urls.py to server GET requeat at `/`.